# Executable automatically deleted upon exit

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

I'm using visual studio community 2013 on Windows 10 home for development of a c# AI application. The application works fine if it runs from the development folder, however, because I want to be able to keep the application running while modifying and compiling existing code, I copied the exe and DLLs (1 exe, 2 DLLs, debug build) to a different folder to be run from there.

When run from the copied folder, the exe (only the exe) is deleted when I close the application. Moreover, I cannot copy the exe back from the development folder because I get "Destination folder access denied". This happens only when I try to copy the exe (other files, including exes with different names, can be copied OK) and I have to reboot to be able to copy the exe back.

I'm not sure even where to start to debug this. Things I tried:
- Check the recycle bin to see if the deleted file is there: no
- Run process monitor to see if the exe name is running anywhere: no
- Exclude the copied folder from antivirus (AVG) scan/check: didn't help
- Make sure I'm running as administrator: yes

Comment: What happens if you run the program from development folder and then close it? Is anything being deleted? Seems like whatever deleting your 
file is not finished properly - therefor the access denied message when you try to copy it again.

Comment: If it runs from the development folder and then closed, nothing is deleted.

Comment: _"the exe (only the exe) is deleted when I close the application"_ -- sounds pretty much like AV is interfering. Have you disabled AV to completely rule it out?

Comment: I stopped all AVG shields permanently, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the folder permissions on the destination directory? This sounds pretty much closer to a folder permission issue.

Since you haven't mentioned the Windows version in question, I am going to be generic on the approach. Try this:

1. Go to folder properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Owner -> Edit
2. Add ownership to your user account
3. Apply changes and retry copying files as see if it still prevails

** Also, in folder permissions, try giving full control to your user account

Comment: As mentioned, I'm running Windows 10 home. The problem is not with the permissions as I can copy other files to the same folder.

Comment: Ok. Another thing you could try (kind of brute force but faster in getting to the bottom of the issue) is to install a tool like 'Unlocker' and check what processes keeping locks on to the file being deleted. I once had a similar instance where a file that i tried deleting actually didn't get deleted due to a hook from Windows Defender; though it appeared as deleted, it was not and it was realized when i tried to copy the file back to the same directory....

Comment: I tried Unlocker, but it doesn't tell you which file is being locked, it only unlocks the files/folders you specify. And since the file is not there, I can't really select it. I tried to set audit policy for the file: 
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder) but could not see file access in the security log (Windows 10 home)